# Fish Shell hangs on startup

Tags: fish

I'm on a Mac, Yosemite. I installed Fish yesterday and it was working fine, but today when opening a new window it just hangs.

My `./config/fish/fish.config` is currently empty so I don't believe its a config issue.

After restarting, running with debug produced the following:

`fish: Could not connect to socket -1, starting fishd`

Grepping showed that `fishd` was not running, so I started `fishd` manually, then ran fish with debugging and got the following:

`fish: Connect to socket /tmp/fish.kscott/fishd.socket at fd 3
fish: Connected to fd 3
fish: Create barrier
fish: before write of 8 chars to fd 3
fish: Wrote message 'BARRIER
'
fish: Sent barrier request`

And fish continues to hang for me, so I'm currently back in bash.

I'm not really sure how to debug further; is there something I'm missing with the setup process?

-- EDIT --

In response to ridiculous_fish below, my config.fish was initially:

```
alias gg 'git grep'

set -x ACKRC '.ackrc'

set -U fish_user_paths $fish_user_paths /opt/local/bin /usr/local/bin /npm/bin /Users/kscott/fish_scripts
```

And the output of a line from `~/.config/fish/fishd.*` is huge:

```
SET fish_user_paths:/usr/local/bin\x1e/Users/kscott/bin\x1e/opt/local/bin\x1e/usr/local/bin\x1e/.... goes on and on for 30 lines`
```

Can I delete this file safely, or clear it out?

Comment: Sometimes users make really huge variables which can bring things to a crawl. Take a look in `~/.config/fish/fishd.*`. Are there any very long lines?

Comment: Yes, fish_user_paths is incredibly long, though in my config file I was only appending 6 or 7 paths. Can I delete or clear out this file?

Comment: @ridiculous_fish edited my question in response to your comment.

Comment: I just face same problem on Fedora 21. It hang around 1 minute to get started. Not sure it's related or not but my ~/.config/fish/fish_history is quite long which contains 13632 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Universal variables are automatically persisted between sessions. So when you write this:

```
set -U fish_user_paths $fish_user_paths /opt/local/bin...
```

That the `$fish_user_paths` variable longer every time you start fish. Eventually it will become so big that it hangs.

To fix it, you can either ensure `fishd` is not running and then edit the file by hand to remove that line, or you can (from fish) just run `set -U fish_user_paths /opt/local/bin /usr/local/bin /npm/bin /Users/kscott/fish_scripts` to set it once.

`set -U` commands are pretty much always a mistake in `config.fish`. We'll likely add a warning for this case - see [#2005](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2005).